# Is a wildcard in SNI valid?

Tags: ssl, sni

Came across a packet capture where the client hello SNI had this value `*.immedia-semi.com`. Is having a wildcard in the SNI valid?

Comment: @Dai from RFC 6066, it mentions that the SNI should be a valid DNS hostname. Having a wildcard doesn't seem to be right according to that? (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6066#section-3)  I understand a wildcard in the certificate SAN is acceptable.

Comment: My mistake - I misunderstood your question. I've deleted my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `server_name` extension (SNI) is intended to specify a hostname. From [RFC 6066](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6066#section-3):

> "HostName" contains the **fully qualified DNS hostname** of the server,
> as understood by the client.

Given that a wildcard is not a valid FQDN it is not valid here either. Similar IP addresses are not FQDN too and are even explicitly forbidden here.

Client TLS implementations usually don't check what is given by the program as SNI too use and thus sometimes broken SNI are seen in the wild, caused by application bugs.

Comment: "Similar IP addresses are not FQDN too and are even explicitly forbidden here." - huh! that's surprising because I thought that TLS could be used to secure hosts identified by IP address - or **any** arbitrary name, not just DNS names - or is that just for SNI?

Comment: @Dai: This is just for SNI. The point of SNI is to have something to distinguish different names for the same IP address. When using the IP address as target no SNI is needed, i.e. makes no sense to use it in the first place.